# Angularjs photo album

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base64, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

Hi I'm making a photoalbum app with angularjs which grabs base-64 encoded image strings from my server and decodes them into images.

The problem is my angularjs app can't seem to decode the base64 strings.  On my template it shows the no image found icon.  I checked the base64 strings and its fine when I embed it straight to the template like this:

```
 <p><img src="data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64, /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLA...etc.</p>'
```

The image will show up.  However I need to grab the photoalbum data from a service within my customer directive (code below).

Can anybody help with this problem?

Here is my code:

directive.js

```
 .directive('photoalbumsDisplay', ['$compile', 'myprofileService', function($compile,       
 myprofileService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            myprofileService.retrieve_albums().then(function(data) {
                var html = [];
                for (var p = 0; p < data.length; p++) {
                    //album photos array
                    var pic = data[p];

                    html += '<p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, ' + pic + '"/></p>';
                }

                element.replaceWith(html)


            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

template.html

```
 <div data-ng-controller="photogalleryCtr" data-ng-init="init()">

    <photoalbums-display></photoalbums-display>

</div>
```

Comment: imho the decoding should happen on the server side.  I know thats not what you are asking for, but it seems like a very curious architecture choice to do it the way you have it.

Comment: I'm using a rest API for serverside.  Also photos are sensitive don't want to leave it in the public folder

Comment: what i meant by decode server side is to have your rest api decode it

Comment: But how do I send my images to my angularjs app then?  What do I return when the app makes api calls

Comment: <img src="yourdomain.com/yourrestapi/#imageID">

Comment: Hmm i'll try that out

Comment: Ok it worked.  I think I will change my architecture choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using ng-src instead of src and getting photos from the scope in your directive instead of getting them inside your directive:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc

Then you can do this in your markup:

```
<photoalbums-display="photos"></photoalbums-display>
```

And change your directive like this:

```
app.directive('photoalbumsDisplay', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            photos: '=photos'
        },
        template: '<p ng-repeat="photo in photos">' +
            '<img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64, {{photo.data}}"></p>'
    };
});
```

And add this to your controller, with the necessary injections:

```
$scope.photos = [];
myprofileService.retrieve_albums().then(function(data) {
    var i, length;
    for (i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i += 1) {
        $scope.photos.push({
            data: data[i]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Here is a plinkr with an added title attribute, I have mocked up the service in it though and the service returns a list of objects instead of strings: http://plnkr.co/edit/fz5FJSlIZe0P1Nfva9a7?p=preview

Comment: I see. Which method would be better though yours or <img src="yourdomain.com/yourrestapi/#imageID"> .  They both work now I'm more concerned about speed of loading the images

Comment: Why not just serve the images dynamically with whatever backend you have and require that a user is logged in to view them?  Serving images at a url, like yourdomain.com/yourrestapi/profile/15/image, that is secured has the same security as serving them as data in an API.  The url solution I think will perform better because they can be cached and you don't have to worry about the data being duplicated in memory by js.  If performance is important you should test it.